# Need data after Last comma in field1 from the Text in Unix

Tags: unix

Need you help on the below query.

$cat sample.txt

```
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298e,,,002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,45675
414d51204d514e55533732355051543051696344201645c6,002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,tgre,ghty
```

Need all fields after last comma "," in field 1.As you can see there are lots of (414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298e,,,)
The output has to be like as below.

Expected Output:

```
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,45675
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,tgre,ghty
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the others do not work here is a perl oneliner:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*?,+(.*)/'
```

Output:

```
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,45675
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,tgre,ghty
```

Comment: Hi Mate, i am getting below error. perl -lnE 'print $1 if /.*?,+(.*)/' sample.txt
Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options).

Comment: @user3847566 try -lne instead of -lnE

Answer (score 0):

Using `egrep` or `grep -E`:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]{24}\s+\S+' your_file
```

Using normal `grep`:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{24\}[[:blank:]]\+[^[:blank:]]\+' your_file
```

Output:

```
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,45675
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,tgre,ghty
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^[^[:blank:]]\+,//' your_file
```

Or

```
sed -e 's/^[^ \t]\+,//' your_file
```

Or just about space:

```
sed -e 's/^[^ ]\+,//' your_file
```

Comment: Hi Mate, grep -o option not available in my unix box(sunos). Would be give me any other option. Thanks

Comment: Not getting desired output. O/p got 414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298e,,,002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,45675
414d51204d514e55533732355051543051696344201645c6,002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,tgre,ghty

Comment: @user3847566 Have you tried all `sed` commands? What do you mean `"O/p"`?

Comment: No luck. same issue and it is not neccessarily i will get + in field2. But i want all fields after last comma in field1.

Comment: @user3847566 Does your file really contain multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell program .

```
cat sample.txt | sed -n 1'p' | tr ',' '\n' | while read word; do
echo $word
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` and `cut` :

- sed to remove empty fields
- cut to select the required fields

**Example:**

```
sed -r 's/,+/,/g' < text.txt | cut -d',' -f2-
```

**Output:**

```
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,45675
002330618820140707134048  ,+0657,tgre,ghty
```

Comment: Hi Mate, It's not that neccessarily that i will get + in the field2.But Field one have commas, i want all fields after last comma in field1

Comment: Isn't this what my cmd is doing ? Or I misunderstood you ? My "+" in the `sed` means "one or more commas"

Comment: Output i got is  cat sample.txt|sed 's/,+/,/g'|cut -d',' -f2-
,,002330618820140707134048  ,0657,,45675
002330618820140707134048  ,0657,tgre,ghty. Moreover sed -r is illegal option in my unix box